# "(flag) ?" Syntax. I don't understand and can't find it with a Google search

Tags: typescript

Could anyone explain the syntax behind the following statement to me?  It's obvious it's a type of "switch statement."  It's what controls the increment or decrement of the updatedUser.favoriteMeCount variable.

However, I can't understand how the "(flag)?" statement is even able to receive a value to then choose to increment or decrement the updatedUser.favoriteMeCount variable.

Can anyone shed any light on this?.  My background (decades ago) was as a C++ developer.

```
let userRef = this.af.database.ref('/users').child(toUserUid);
userRef.once('value').then( user =>{
let updatedUser = user.val();
(flag)? updatedUser.favoriteMeCount++ : updatedUser.favoriteMeCount--;
userRef.update(updatedUser);
```

Where does "flag" get its value from?

Comment: `flag` must be some variable set somewhere.  The syntax you're having trouble with is the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: The conditional operator is exactly what I was having trouble with.  Thank you so much.  Sucks to be a n00b starting out.  The response is  much appreciated.